# VISIO not allowing grouping the shapes in database diagram

Tags: microsoft-office, sql-server, microsoft-visio, microsoft-visio-2010

After reverse  engineering a SQL Db in VISIO 2010, I tried the this [MSDN tutorial](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Group-or-ungroup-shapes-in-Visio-18fa3c8e-c3ba-4203-8624-01e01c6496be) to group some shapes (tables) in the database diagram but got the following error:

**Error**

> VISIO database solution shapes cannot be included in group

**Question**: How can  I group shapes in a database diagram in VISIO? Or, are  there any workarounds?

Answer (score 0):

The reason that database shapes (and some others) are not allowed to be grouped is that the software that works with these shapes is expecting shapes of a certain format, and does not know what to do with them if they are grouped.

However, in this case there is a workaround.
On the ribbon go to **File** -> **Options** -> **Advanced** and near the bottom you will see a tick-box marked **Enable Automation Events**. Untick this and click OK.

Go back to your drawing and do whatever grouping you need to do. When you are done do back to the Options box and re-tick the **Enable Automation Events** box. Do not forget to do this as without it not only will the database diagram not work correctly (some menu options will not work) but also many other special operations will not work correctly. Don't add or delete shapes to/from your diagram, do as little as possible while in this state. Take a backup of the document first.